# error in loading database drivers in hibernate console configuration

Tags: hibernate

my configuration file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root$12</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <mapping resource="com.sst.Course.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
   </hibernate-configuration>
```

I am getting an error in loading database drivers at the time of creating console configuration.

Comment: can you post your error?

Comment: in console configuration window my error shows like this : Problems while loading database driverclass (org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

And in your console configuration verify database connection (Drivers, jar, ...)

Comment: intially i used this url after that i changed